# How to write linq extension method for all types?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-extensions

I have this method that I want to write:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> CutTo<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Func<int> func)
{
    int index = func();
    // here I can write something for all types or switch all
    // the types and write code for every type
}
```

What is the easiest way to code this for all TSource types?

**Edit:** Black Bear writes that this already works for all types but this is not true. Mono writes like this:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource> (this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
{
    Check.SourceAndPredicate (source, predicate);

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource> (
        StaticCall (
            MakeGeneric (MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod (), typeof (TSource)),
            source.Expression,
            Expression.Quote (predicate)));
}
```

Comment: This already works for all types

Comment: What should CutTo do, and what's the meaning of func and its return value?

Answer (score 1):

## First solution (cleaner one)

**Will work only with types that implement specific interface**

Create interface `IHaveId`

```
public interface IHaveId
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then every model with `Id` propery should implement `IHaveId`. Example

```
public class Post : IHaveId
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And then write your `CutTo` method like:

```
public static IQueryable<T> CutTo<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Func<int> func)
    where T: IHaveId
{
    int index = func();
    return source.Where(x => x.Id == index);
}
```

The idea is that every implementation of `IHaveId` will have `int` property called `Id` and then you can limit `CutTo` method to work only with implementations of `IHaveId` and use their `Id` property.

## Second solution (uglier)

**Will work with any type that keeps Entity Framework convention for naming primary keys**

1. Use reflection over `typeof(TSource)` to find property named `Id` or `typeof(TSource).Name + "Id"`
2. Again with reflection build `Expression<Func<TSource, int>>` and apply it in `IQueryable<T> source` with `Where` clause.

Comment: I want every available type to be included.

Comment: I've edited my answer with second solution that is more generic but uglier.